# How to fix bidirectional text with numbers?

Tags: html, css, bidirectional

I got this text and I need to make the number inside of it to be rendered as a number should.

[image]

I tried several ways to solve it using `dir="auto/rtl/ltr"` also using unicode-bidi in a css selector and nothing fixed it.

Comment: can you provide some html and css code with what you have so we can test it?

Comment: How about wrapping the phone in separate span and setting `dir="ltr"` on it, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2mbcyqog/)? Bidirectional algorithm is a mess (by a reason, though).

Comment: @raina77ow that fixed my problem. Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way around is wrapping the phone number (and similar text) into a separate container with `dir="ltr"` set on it. For example:

```
<span>אחד שני <span dir="ltr">+1(617) 522-22-33</span> אחד שני </span>
```

Depending on content's type, you can use either generic `<span>` as in this example, or more specific element.